# How do I print console.log this 0?

Tags: jquery, console

[image]

This was from `console.log($(this));` I tried `console.log($(this).0);` but it didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried console.log($(this)[0]); ?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you mean:

```
console.log( $(this).get(0) );
```

Comment: Very strange. It prints HTML.

Comment: It's the expected result as this and the other answer both deliver the queried HTML node that ist stored in the jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want `console.log($(this)[0]);`

Comment: Very strange. It prints HTML.

Comment: Why is that strange?  You're asking for the first item in the array, which just happens to be an HTML DOM node.